# Can't find InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, tbb

I get error when publish Page after adding `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder` to Render Page Content (TBB).

```
<CompoundTemplate xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.3/CompoundTemplate">
  <TemplateInvocation>
    <Template xlink:href="tcm:2-51-2048" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Generate DXA R2 Page Model" />
    <TemplateParameters>
      <Parameters xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/dynamicpage">
        <expandLinkDepth xmlns="http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/dynamicpage">10</expandLinkDepth>
        <modelBuilderTypeNames>DefaultModelBuilder;DefaultPageMetaModelBuilder;EclModelBuilder;ContextExpressionsModelBuilder;InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder</modelBuilderTypeNames>
      </Parameters>
    </TemplateParameters>
  </TemplateInvocation>
</CompoundTemplate>
```

> Could not load type
>   'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Data.InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder' from assembly
>   'Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.merged, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

That's interesting!

You can see that the `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder` is expected to be in namespace `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Data`, but it actually is in namespace `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2.Data`. See [GitHub](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/2.0/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder.cs)

Interestingly, the [`DataModelBuilderPipeline` in DXA 2.0 release](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/release/2.0/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/DataModelBuilderPipeline.cs) does expect it to be in `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2.Data`, but you can see that the last commit before DXA 2.0 release was to fix this expected namespace.

Could it be that you're using a DXA 2.0 pre-release version? Maybe a DXA 2.0 CTP2?

A work-around can be to specify a qualified type name, so `Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2.Data.InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder`,  but if you're still using a pre-release version, you should definitely consider upgrading to a release version.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you verify that you are indeed looking at the proper compound template. The `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder` which is mentioned in the error message is available OOTB, however looking at your template's xml, it is **not referenced**.

What you have is `InheritPageModelBuilder` vs `InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder`. Is `InheritPageModelBuilder` your custom Model Builder?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake in question. I mean InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder*